# Should converter using service or rpc?

Tags: java, lambda, converters

As start using java 8, I prefer to use `Function<T, R>` to convert one model to another. For example

```
public Class BizConverter {
  public static Function<BizA, BizB> aToB() {
    a -> {
       B b = new B();
       // simple set property from a
       ...
       return b;
    }
  }
}
```

Above is a pure converter, static method return a convert function.
But when the business become compliated, I start puting some business into converter, such as biz default value, constant.

However this is not engough at all. Sometime the converter have to call service or rpc to get target property value. I wondered that should I put service into converter's static method or just keep pure converter while prepare target value in invoker's service? Besides that can converter be a service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: well...its up to you really, but a SOLID design demands a single responsability principle (the **S**) so maybe you sould debate weather its the converter responsability to do other stuff (and it may very well be) but really, nobody knows

Comment: @JSeler yes. May use converter as a service is not a bad solution